# Wear OS ANR on broadcast act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm getting regular ANR's on my WearOS app regarding the android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF broadcast, which I haven't registered for.

It happens primarily on Samsung Galaxy Watch4 devices, like the one I am developing on.

The case is complicated and googling didn't help much. Here is the flow, bear with me:

1. The app launches normally, works as expected;
2. The watch is turned downwards and the screen goes off. So far so good;
3. I wait about 20 seconds for the Wear OS to move my app to the background and return to the watch face;
4. I see in ADB that the app is running;
5. I turn the watch up, the screen turns on and I see the watch face, my app is in the background;
6. I turn the watch back down, wait a few seconds and then it crashes with ANR

`Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x50200010 (has extras) }`

I've been developing for a while and I know how to read the logs, but I found nothing there that could lead me to what registers for this broadcast and does not respond. The only possible reason I can think of is the imports I am using, which are scarce. Here they are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
}
```

SDK:

```
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 31
```

I did suspect the splashscreen as closest to the screen and removed it, but the ANR happened nevertheless.

I even tried implementing my own BroadcastReceiver that does not unregister on onPause in order to give some answer to the system, even added `this.goAsync().finish();` to its `onReceive()`, but it didn't help.

Has anyone bumped into this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possibly related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220190983

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is exactly on the spot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE 2022-04-24:**

After the last OTA update for the Galaxy 4 watches, version FVC8, the issue seems to be resolved. Keeping this here for historical reasons while versions prior to FVC8 are still active.

---

A few hours later, and after Yuri Schimke's comment I understood that there is a bug report to Google exactly for this.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220190983

I was able to circumvent the issue by implementing a `BroadcastReceiver` for **BOTH** `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` **AND** `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` that does nothing but logging the event and calling `this.goAsync().finish();`. This `BroadcastReceiver` is registered on `onCreate` and unregistered on `onDestroy`.

This way the ANR does NOT happen anymore, though I'm not yet certain as of what effect it has on the battery.